# PhoneApplicationPage can not resolve StaticResource

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xaml, windows-phone-7.1, resourcedictionary

At some point Visual Studio (2010) stopped resolving any static Resources (Brushes, Styles, ViewModel locators, etc.) on all PhoneApplicationPage. However any VisualEllement from with a UserControl can see all StaticResources.

***Note**: All resources worked before and there wasn't any changes to the pages in terms of XAML.*

Any ideas why this is happening?

**Temp fix:** Temporary fix I came up with is to add All resources to PhoneApplicationPage.Resources so before **trying** to resolve resources at the application level, elements will resolve them from RD of the PhoneApplicationPage.

**Edit:** All StaticResources are resolved when running in Blend, this issues seems to happen only in VS. Also when creating a new Page in the solution it also can't resolve any StaticResources.

Comment: Have you tried repairing the install or reinstalling?

Comment: You mean reinstall VS? If so, I think several people in our team started to experience the same issue.

Comment: I meant to try reinstalling the WP SDK. But if it's happening when the same code is used on different machines it would indicate something specific to the code. It may therefore require reverting to earlier versions to try and identify the change that caused the issue. :(

Comment: Yeap, that potentially could point out where is the problem is. If I have time to do that, I will do it. For now I will use a temp fix.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things you could try.

1. Create a new page.  Can you access StaticResources from there?  If
   you can, you can narrow down the cause to the xaml for the pages
   where you are having trouble now.  Check the xmlns declarations from
   the new [age against the old to verify nothing has been accidentally
   removed, for example.
2. If you have access to Expression Blend, try
   opening the solution there and then right-clicking on an element to
   apply a resource.  I have a feeling that the tool might be able to
   fix issues, but never having seen this behaviour before I can't
   guarantee it.

Also, are your resources defined in app.xaml, or have you specified another file containing the resources?  If the latter, has the plumbing to tie the extra file in gone AWOL somehow?

Comment: One important thing I haven't mentioned is that during run time and in Blend those Resources do get resolved. As for new page, it also unable to resolve any static resource dictionaries.

Comment: As for Resources, they are defined in App.xaml, both MergedDictionaries and simple Resources (like MVVM Light ViewModel locator)